# add JS code in product detailed page magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

During installation of my plugin , I want to include piece of javascript code in the product detailed page source. How it can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add javascript code then implement code in `view.phtml` in directory

```
app\design\frontend\youtheme\youtheme\template\catalog\product\view.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your module file path : app/design/frontend/yourtheme/yourtheme/layout/modulename.xml  and then add your js file inside skin folder it will be called in your product view page header

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="head">
         <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/yourjsfile.js</name></action>
    </reference>
<catalog_product_view>
```